# question about neighbourhood and family of sets

Tags: general-topology

Verify the following two properties regarding a compact topological space $X$ and $\mathcal{F}$, a family of real valued continuous functions defined on $X$ :

$(a)$ For every $x\in X$, there exists an open neighbourhood $U(x)$ of $x$ and a function $f\in \mathcal{F}$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $U(x)$ is identically zero.

$(b)$ Let $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a collection of functions in $C[0,1]$ such that given any finite subfamily of functions, its members vanish at some common point (which depends on that subfamily). Then there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f_i(x_0)=0$ for all $i\in I$.

I knew about neighbourhood property of continuous functions which said if $f$ is continuous on some interval, and at some point $c$ in the interval, if $f(c)\neq 0$, then there exists a neighbourhood of $c$ such that $f$ keeps same sign as $f(c)$ throughout the neighbourhood. Has it something to do in the first part? I also have no idea about the second part where to start.

Answer (score 0):

(A)Fix $x\in X$, take the function $f(x)=0$ $\forall x \in X$ and $U(x)=X$, this solves the first question!!

(B) Consider the sets $\{f_i^{-1}(0)\}$ where $i\in I$, these are clearly **closed** in $X$, and the intersection of finitely many of then is non-empty, hence intersection of all of them is non-empty(as $X$ is **compact**).

Comment: In $(A)$, how can we set $U(x)=X$? Since $U(x)$ is open whereas $X$ is compact, therefore closed?

Comment: $X$ is both open and closed is $X$ (By definition, see definition of topological spaces, its the 1st criteria, X and empty set is open!!)

It doesn't matter whether it's compact or not.